# Extracting coefficients from a partial differential equation

Tags: pattern-matching, differential-equations

Frequently, I come across the following problem: 
How to rewrite a complicated partial differential equation in a more clear way? I would like to create some order by collecting terms that are equal.

For example, this rather messy equation
$0 = \frac{1}{4} l^4 m^4 y F^{(0,1)}(x,y)-6 l^2 M^2 y F^{(0,1)}(x,y)+\Lambda  F^{(0,1)}(x,y)$,

can be written more clear as

$0 = \text{newform} = a_{0001} F^{(0,1)}(x,y)+a_{0101} y F^{(0,1)}(x,y)$

with $a_{0101}=\frac{l^4 m^4}{4}-6 l^2 M^2$ and $a_{0001}=\Lambda$.

My question is how to determine the coefficients from a given PDE? To make it more tangible, suppose I have a partial differential equation of f(x,y) that is quadratic in f and has order 6 derivatives in derivatives. It can be written as

$0 = \sum_{i,j,k,l} a_{i j k l} x^i y^{j}F^{(k,l)}(x,y) + \sum_{i,j,k,l,m,n} b_{i j k l m n} x^i y^{j}F^{(k,l)}(x,y)F^{(m,n)}(x,y)$

I want to use Mathematica to

1. Rewrite the PDE into the above form; i.e. replace calculate all the coefficients
2. Do not include terms with that have a zero coefficient in this new form
3. Create a replacement rule for each coefficient.
4. Check that this new form of writing eq is indeed equivalent.

How can I do this?
If point 1 - 3 are established, then point 4 is easy:
Just check that the following adds up to zero

```
oldform - newform /. substitutionrule
```

To give you an idea, these are some of the terms that appear in my PDE.
$\small{l^4 m^4 F(x,y) -57 l^4 \Lambda M^2 F(x,y) + l^4 m^4 y F^{(0,1)}(x,y)+ 57 l^4 \Lambda M^2 y F^{(0,1)}(x,y)-24 l^2 M^2 y F^{(0,1)}(x,y)}$
$+ \small{2 M^2 y^8 F^{(0,1)}(x,y) F^{(0,5)}(x,y)-4 M^2 y^8 F^{(2,4)}(x,y)+4 M^2 y^6 F(x,y) F^{(0,4)}(x,y) = 0}$

Here is the `InputForm` of this 'toy PDE'

```
eqn = l^4*m^4*F[x, y] - 57*l^4*Lambda*M^2*F[x, y] + l^4*m^4*y*Derivative[0, 1][F][x, y] 
- 24*l^2*M^2*y*Derivative[0, 1][F][x, y]
+ 57*l^4*Lambda*M^2*y*Derivative[0, 1][F][x, y] 
+ 4*M^2*y^6*F[x, y]*Derivative[0, 4][F][x, y] 
+  2*M^2*y^8*Derivative[0, 1][F][x, y]*Derivative[0, 5][F][x, y]
- 4*M^2*y^8*Derivative[2, 4][F][x, y]
```

And more convenient to copy into a notebook is this form

```
eqn = l^4*m^4*F[x, y] - 57*l^4*Lambda*M^2*F[x, y] + l^4*m^4*y*Derivative[0, 1][F][x, y] - 4*l^2*M^2*y*Derivative[0, 1][F][x, y] +  57*l^4*Lambda*M^2*y*Derivative[0, 1][F][x, y] + 4*M^2*y^6*F[x, y]*Derivative[0, 4][F][x, y] +  2*M^2*y^8*Derivative[0, 1][F][x,y]*Derivative[0, 5][F][x, y] - 4*M^2*y^8*Derivative[2, 4][F][x, y]
```

Update:

Pillsy gave a nice solution that does exactly (1)-(4). To see what kind of powers of x, y, $\partial_x$ and $\partial_y$ are contained in the example PDE I use his code, and I add

```
Total[coeffRules /. {(a[i_, j_, k_, l_] -> coeff_) :> 
Subscript[a, i, j, k, l]*x^i*y^j*
 Derivative[k, l][F], (b[i_, j_, k_, l_, m_, n_] -> coeff_) :> 
Subscript[b, i, j, k, l, m, n]*x^i*y^j*
 Derivative[k, l][F] Derivative[m, n][F]}]
```

This gives
$\small{y^8 a_{0,8,2,4} F^{(2,4)}+3 y a_{0,1,0,1} F^{(0,1)}+2 F a_{0,0,0,0}+y^8 b_{0,8,0,1,0,5} F^{(0,1)} F^{(0,5)}+F y^6 b_{0,6,0,0,0,4} F^{(0,4)}}$

Now it is much easer to see what kind of PDE this is. There is one more thing I would like to ask. How can I avoid the double counting  of terms that results for example in the factor 3 in $3 y a_{0,1,0,1} F^{(0,1)}$?

This works, I think

```
% /. {Times[a_Integer, b_] -> b, Times[b_, a_Integer] -> b}
```

$\small{y^8 a_{0,8,2,4} F^{(2,4)}+y a_{0,1,0,1} F^{(0,1)}+F a_{0,0,0,0}+y^8 b_{0,8,0,1,0,5} F^{(0,1)} F^{(0,5)}+F y^6 b_{0,6,0,0,0,4} F^{(0,4)}}$

Comment: I see a -1 for my question. What could be the reason for that? How can I improve my question?

Comment: I added hopefully more readable `InputForm` of the expression in your `eq`. Please check if it correctly represents the expression you intended.

Comment: @kguler It seems you have replaced `x` with `1` by a mistake.

Comment: @Artes, Thank you; just noticed it and fixed it.

Comment: @Artes thank you for the improvements. I made a mistake myself by adding a cubic term in F. I will repair it.

Comment: @sjdh  Your question will be interesting if you put everything in correct order and clarify a bit more what you are looking for.

Comment: @Artes Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So, this is a solvable problem, but my solution is hacky, not cookbook by any means. It involves using `Apply` to make algebraic expressions into lists of terms and factors, and it relies the optional *levelspec* arguments for [`Cases`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Cases.html) and [`DeleteCases`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DeleteCases.html) being infinity.

Also note the use of `Block` to temporarily suspend the evaluation rules for `Derivative`, so that I can make things more regular by replacing `F[x, y]` with `Derivative[0, 0][F][x, y]`. This is a frequently useful trick when doing algebraic manipulations.

```
coeffRules = Block[{Derivative},
  With[{terms = 
     Apply[List, eqn /. F[x, y] :> Derivative[0, 0][F][x, y]]},
   Cases[
    Flatten@Map[CoefficientRules[#, {x, y}] &, terms],

    (pows_ -> rhs_) :> 
     With[{degs = 
        Flatten[Cases[rhs, Derivative[degs___][F][x, y] :> degs, 
          Infinity]]},
      With[{args = Join[pows, degs]},
        If[Length@args == 4, a @@ args, b @@ args]]
       -> DeleteCases[rhs, Derivative[___][F][x, y], Infinity]]]]];
```

Here, `coeffRules` is just a list of rules for the `a` and `b` coefficients you described:

```
{a[0, 0, 0, 0] -> l^4 m^4, a[0, 0, 0, 0] -> -57 l^4 Lambda M^2, 
 a[0, 1, 0, 1] -> l^4 m^4, a[0, 1, 0, 1] -> -4 l^2 M^2, 
 a[0, 1, 0, 1] -> 57 l^4 Lambda M^2, b[0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 4] -> 4 M^2, 
 b[0, 8, 0, 1, 0, 5] -> 2 M^2, a[0, 8, 2, 4] -> -4 M^2}
```

You can then verify that this answer is correct like so:

```
In[17]:= Total[coeffRules /. {
             (a[i_, j_, k_, l_] -> coeff_) :> 
              coeff*x^i*y^j*Derivative[k, l][F][x, y],
             (b[i_, j_, k_, l_, m_, n_] -> coeff_) :> 
              coeff*x^i*y^j*
               Derivative[k, l][F][x, y] Derivative[m, n][F][x, y]}] - eqn
Out[17]= 0
```

Hopefully this is enough to get you started.

**EDIT** to add: In reply to @sjdh's comment, you can collect all the terms with the same left-hand side using `Map`, `GatherBy` and `Total`:

```
In[69]:= gatheredRules = Map[
          (#[[1, 1]] -> Total@#[[All, -1]]) &,
          GatherBy[coeffRules, First]]
Out[69]= {a[0, 0, 0, 0] -> l^4 m^4 - 57 l^4 Lambda M^2, 
          a[0, 1, 0, 1] -> l^4 m^4 - 4 l^2 M^2 + 57 l^4 Lambda M^2, 
          b[0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 4] -> 4 M^2, b[0, 8, 0, 1, 0, 5] -> 2 M^2, 
          a[0, 8, 2, 4] -> -4 M^2}
```

In order to verify that this matches the original equation, use `Simplify`:

```
In[70]:= Simplify[eqn - 
          Total[gatheredRules /. {
            (a[i_, j_, k_, l_] -> coeff_) :> 
             coeff*x^i*y^j* Derivative[k, l][F][x, y], 
            (b[i_, j_, k_, l_, m_, n_] -> coeff_) :> 
             coeff*x^i*y^j*Derivative[k, l][F][x, y] Derivative[m, n][F][x, y]}]]
Out[70]:= 0
```

The secret to doing these kind of algebraic manipulations in Mathematica is that algebraic expressions are just list structures with some fancy heads, and thus can be manipulated with exactly the same functions (like `Map` and `Cases`) as lists. Indeed, as you become more familiar with Mathematica, you'll discover that pretty much everything, from graphics to imported XML to notebooks themselves, can be manipulated this way.

Comment: Now there are two rules for the same coefficient: a[0, 0, 0, 0] -> l^4 m^4  and a[0, 0, 0, 0] -> -57 l^4 Lambda M^2. How can I replace them by one rule a[0, 0, 0, 0] -> l^4 m^4 + -57 l^4 Lambda M^2 ?